# Does Grimms' blood only work on Hexenbiest or can it be used on all Wesen to remove their powers?

Tags: grimm

Can the blood of a Grimm be used on all Wesen to remove their powers, or does it only work on  Hexenbiest?

Comment: you know I was asking myself this exact same question on Friday and I think I have an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was just thinking about this watching Friday's episode, and after some deliberation I think the answer we're "supposed to" arrive at is that this special power only works on Hexenbiest. As far as an official canon answer, there has never been one, but based on the information we have, I think that's the most reasonable explanation.

I think the issue here is that a Hexenbiest's powers are not "natural" in the way that other Wesen are. When Monroe or Rosalee *woge*, they gain access to talents from their Wesen side because those things are a fundamental part of their "creature" half. For example, you couldn't really take a Blutbad and take away their innate strength -- they wouldn't be a Blutbad anymore. A Hexenbiest, however, has power to perform magic that seems to be *because of*, but not necessarily an *innate part of*, their Hexenbiest side. In particular, note that Adalind's magic seems to be just as potent when she is in or out of *woge*, while other Wesen's abilities are dramatically enhanced when they *woge*. Grimm blood is able to nullify this extra gift that Hexenbiest have because it's somehow *different* from what the other Wesen have.

I also tend to think this must be true because, in all the time since then, we've never once seen *anyone* even suggest using Nick's blood to neutralize a Wesen. This includes Wesen that Monroe claimed were almost impossible to defeat. If Nick's blood could nullify the power of any Wesen that ingested it, I would expect by now for Nick (and every other Grimm in history) to have loaded his crossbow up with Nick's-blood arrows in case of emergency.

Even moreso, I feel like we've seen at least a few instances where Nick got into fights with Wesen that resulted in him bleeding all over them; if his blood was able to destroy their Wesen side I would expect them to be terrified of that possibility, but we see nothing like that reaction from any of them.

I also realize that, out-of-universe this may have been a case of the writers deciding after the fact that they screwed up, and made things *too easy* on Nick, so they simply decided to drop the issue and hope no one notices. In-universe, though, I think the only logical explanation is that a Grimm's ability to depower a Hexenbiest is somehow special to that species of Wesen, and not a general catch-all ability.

---

A related aspect of this, which I also wondered way back when we first saw Nick take Adalind's power, is whether Adalind still qualified as a Wesen. I think now we have to assume that she did, mostly because she passed those powers on to her child, even though she was not in possession of them when she got pregnant. Even before they knew that the father was also part-Hexenbiest, people (I think Rosalee?) made mention of the baby having powers because it was "the child of a Hexenbiest". To me, this signifies that Adalind never stopped being a Wesen, she simply stopped being able to use her gift for magic.

Comment: I disagree with the last statement.  I thought it was highly insinuated (skull on the belly) that the treatments that allowed her to regain her wicked powers affected her child in utero.  Nick's mom also stated outright that is the reason the child is so unusually powerful and advanced.